# Get the error '/etc/environment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64: Permission denied'

Tags: permissions, dpkg, java

When running the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev` I get the following output.

```bsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.2.1-8).
python-dev is already the newest version (2.7.15~rc1-1).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is something wrong with my java configuration?

Comment: You can try to run `sudo apt install install-info`, and then run your command (he said that the package `install-info` isn't fully-installed/installed)

Comment: Tried the command but it also returns this error '/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64: Permission denied'

Comment: add this as an edit instead as a comment, it would be easier to understand and to read

Comment: You probably have a syntax error in your `/etc/environment` file - erroneous whitespace around an assignment (`JAVA_HOME= /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` in place of `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`) for example

Comment: @steeldriver that was the exact issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> From the comment by @steeldriver

This is probably a syntax error in `/etc/environment`

For example :

```
JAVA_HOME= /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

in place of

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue

Comment: Perfect, ! So, could you please accept the answer using the green check mark ?